# Why does converting Bitrate using ffmpeg from 124 to 96 reduces the duration of my mp3 file?

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp3

I wanted to convert my mp3 files to a lower bitrate. But upon conversion from 124K to 96k, it reduced my file duration from 4:01 to 3:54. Why is that so?

The syntax used for conversion is :

```
exec("ffmpeg -i com.mp3 -b:a 96k com96.mp3");
```

The original duration was 4:01 but after conversion it became 3:54. Is there anything wrong with my syntax or does a mp3 file loses bits of its data during conversion from higher to lower bitrate?

Comment: Are you sure the mp3 is actually 124K and not 128K? The usual expected bitrate for mp3 would be 128K... If it is really 124K then try testing: `-b:a 128K` and see if duration still reduces to 3:54?

Comment: After converting to 128k the duration remains the same as 3:54. But the original duration is 4:01 @VC.One

Comment: The duration might be different but for each K size you still hear the full track right (they start and finish at same sounds) regardless of duration? The strange 124K number might be confusing media players when they calculate duration. I suspect the correct time is 3:54 so go with that. Only worry if sound is cropped (_eg:_ is missing last 7 seconds of actual audio).

Comment: Does the log of the conversion cmd show a line like "Estimating duration from bitrate"?

Comment: What happens if i convert that media using an incorrect bitrate e.g. 150k ?

Answer (score 1):

124k isn't a normal bitrate for an MP3.  Either your file is using a free-format constant bitrate (very rare... I've actually never seen one), or this bitrate is some average of a few variable bitrate frames.

What makes you think this file is 124k and 04:01 in duration?

What I suspect is that you have a normal VBR file, and whatever is showing you this is using the average of frames to show you a bitrate, and using that average against the file size in bytes to estimate the duration.

MP3 doesn't have built-in timestamps.  It's just MPEG frame after MPEG frame until the end.  Short of additional metadata or muxing it into another container, the only ways to get a duration are to read through the entire file, or to estimate the duration based on bitrate and file size.  With a variable bitrate, you can expect your duration to be somewhat inaccurate.

I suspect the actual audio in the file is 03:54 in duration.

Finally, I don't know what your use case is, but the size difference between 128k and 96k isn't very much, but the quality difference is.  If you want to save bandwidth, there are better codecs (i.e. Opus or AAC).  Also, you shouldn't go from a lossy codec to another lossy codec... you end up wasting bandwidth on trying to encode artifacts, damaging quality even further along the way.

Comment: The properties file shows that its bitrate is 124k and its duration is 4:01. During playback too the duration appears 4:01

Comment: @infinitiayush What do you mean by "the properties file", specifically?  Can you open a hex editor and show a couple of the MPEG frame hearders?

Comment: by the way as you mentioned "there are better codecs (i.e. Opus or AAC)". So, I just wanted to know which if best codec and format for online streaming that uses minimum bandwidth with best sound and performance?

Comment: The details tab on the properties dialog box on windows.

Comment: @infinitiayush The bitrate the Windows property dialog tells you is averaging across frames in your VBR file.  For that same reason, it doesn't know how long your audio is.  As I said, the better codecs are Opus and AAC.  Opus is marginally better than AAC, but its real benefit is that there are no codec royalties to be paid.  Opus is somewhat less compatible than AAC, but barely so these days.  If you don't have a lossless source to go back to, stick with the MP3s you already have.

Comment: No, but going from MP3 to another lossy format will definitely make things worse.